Using MAUI Blazor Hybrid...... can't redirect to any other pages
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/Login");
    }
}

I'm trying to go to the /login page upon running the application.
Login contains a register button that should redirect to the /register page, but it keeps on redirecting to /login.

"register button that should redirect to the /register" where is the button in your code? Please include markup.
